# Android:How to add arrayadapter.getitem(i) to ArrayList<*>? in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Android Studio converted java code to kotlin facing problem in adding a list of objects in kotlin

**javacode**

```
  private List _items = new Arraylist();// for understanding
  private ArrayAdaper _arrayAdapter= (ArrayAdaper)getAdapter; // for understanding

  @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        if (null != _arrayAdapter) {

            // Refresh content #6
            // Change Start
            // Description: The items were only set initially, not reloading the data in the
            // spinner every time it is loaded with items in the adapter.
            _items.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < _arrayAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                _items.add(_arrayAdapter.getItem(i));
            }
            // Change end.

            _searchableListDialog.show(scanForActivity(_context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Kotlin code

```
  private var _items:MutableList<*>?=null //for understanding
  private var _arrayAdapter:ArrayAdapter<*>?=null  //for understanding

  override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (null != _arrayAdapter) {

            // Refresh content #6
            // Change Start
            // Description: The items were only set initially, not reloading the data in the
            // spinner every time it is loaded with items in the adapter.
            _items!!.clear()
            for (i in 0 until _arrayAdapter!!.count) {
                _items!!.add(_arrayAdapter!!.getItem(i))//Type mismatch required nothing Found Any?
            }
            // Change end.
            _searchableListDialog!!.show(scanForActivity(_context)!!.fragmentManager, "TAG")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

i am facing problem in **_items!!.add(_arrayAdapter!!.getItem(i))** in kotlin.it works fine in java but gives error in kotlin `Type mismatch required nothing Found Any?` if I cast to nothing error goes but in runtime on click of spinner I am getting error `string cannot cast to void`

Comment: It looks like you were using raw types in your Java (which you aren't supposed to but is allowed by the compiler), and so they were converted to star projected types in Kotlin, which makes it impossible to add anything to the list. When you instantiate your list and you specify the type of the list, don't use star projection. If you have trouble with that, please share your code where you declare the list and instantiate the list.

Comment: yes thank you i replace * type to ANY then it worked fine